# Jetty vs Weblogic Axis Response deserialization difference

Tags: jetty, weblogic, axis

I am testing my application with both Jetty(Eclipse) & Weblogic. I am calling an axis web service, receive a response and deserialize it. While everything works like a charm in Jetty, when I pack & deploy my application to weblogic I receive

`org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid element in 
com.xxx.yyyy.soa.schemas.INVOICE_ITEMType - CHARGE_TYPE`

I am sure, both call the same Web service URL.
I decompiled the INVOICE_ITEMType class at war that I deploy to weblogic and made sure there is CHARGE_TYPE at INVOICE_ITEMType class. 
What should I do to further investigate the case? I am stuck

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally realized that it is a classloader issue. My application unfortunately calls different web services from same third party company, whose interfaces re-uses same named-packeged objects with different implementations.